# Is it possible to create an OpenGL, GLCanvas() element on MacOS X 10.15 (Java)?

Tags: java, macos, opengl, macos-catalina, jogl

I am currently attempting to update a program that utilizes OpenGL. I need to get the program to work on MacOS X 10.15. I am using JDK SE 14 and the most recent version of JOGL found at https://jogamp.org/.
The issue I run into is when the program tries to create a `GLCanvas()` or `GLJPanel()`, it will instantly crash. Below is the snippet of code that causes the crash.

```
public void initFrame(){
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    JRootPane root = frame.getRootPane( );   // make small title bar
    root.putClientProperty( "Window.style", "small" );
    
   GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();

    frame.setUndecorated(undecorated);
    canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
    canvas.addMouseListener(this);
    canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    

    frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    frame.setLocation(frameX,frameY);

    frame.add(canvas);

    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas,33);  

    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    animator.start();
}
```

The following error is produced when the code reaches GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas()

```
   WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3 (file:/Users/bendavidson/NetBeansProjects/mlsim-master/lib/gluegen-rt.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-08-24 14:59:37.054 java[1489:26665] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31959797 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6a653a9e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3198211c -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff2eb6eddc -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 310
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff2eb56842 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1416
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff2eb562b3 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
    6   libnativewindow_macosx.jnilib       0x000000012f2053fe Java_jogamp_nativewindow_macosx_OSXUtil_CreateNSWindow0 + 398
    7   ???                                 0x000000011c5bb6b0 0x0 + 4770739888
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Java Result: 134
```

I am not sure how to interpret this error, and was wondering if there were any workarounds to getting `GLCanvas()` to work on MacOS X 10.15. I plan to switch the entire application to Metal in the coming months, but I need a quick fix for an upcoming project.

Comment: Rather ask your question on the official JogAmp forum. Don't worry about the warnings, use the latest release candidate of JOGL 2.4.0 to get rid of most of them. It works like a charm.

Comment: @gouessej So turns out I wasn't using the most recent release of JOGL... I thought that when selecting the current zip on the Jogamp website one would get the most recent version. Turns out it was version 2.3.2 not 2.4. Found JOGL 2.4.0, and it works fine now!

Comment: It's a release candidate, not a release. When the release is ready, what you name the current version will become JOGL 2.4.0. I'm glad to see that it works for you.